# error validating data when creating Kubernetes Deployment manifest

Tags: kubernetes

```
error validating data: API version "apps/v1beta2" isn't supported, 
only supports API versions  
["v1" "batch/v1" "batch/v2alpha1" "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1" "federation/v1beta1" "certificates/v1alpha1" 
"componentconfig/v1alpha1" 
"extensions/v1beta1" "policy/v1alpha1" "apps/v1alpha1" 
"authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1" "authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" 
"autoscaling/v1"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn 
validation off with --validate=false
```

How can i resolve this without turning validation off which seems risky?
What determines which API versions are supported?
Is it the version of kubectl or dashboard?

**UPDATE:**
i used the command
`kubectl api-versions`
to find that my kubectl supports apps/v1beta2.
So it looks like there is another layer of API checking/versioning in the Dashboard?

**Details**
`kubectl version --short`
Client Version: v1.11.0
Server Version: v1.9.8

Comment: If you don't provide details (such as: what `kind` and what Kubernetes version you're on) then it's hard to help you. So, please update your question with `kubectl version --short` and what you're trying to deploy (based on your post title, I'd assume `Deployment`?)

Comment: Please post pod logs here for further analysis of your issue.

Comment: It's nonsense to ask for pod logs since the deployment hasn't been submitted to the API server yet …

Comment: I have updated with details from `kubectl version`. I am doing a .yaml Deployment manifest.